# get first value from array column database

Tags: laravel

I need to get the fist item an array from select database using loop for but when i do't my outfit display all the value for array

```
public function index() {
    $hall=DB::table('halls')
        ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
        ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')
        ->get();

    $results =[];

    foreach ($hall as $halls ) {

        $array=$halls->image_path ;
        for ($i=0; $i<$array; $i++) { 
            $halls=$array[0];
        }
        array_push($results, $halls);
    }

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

**JSON Output**

> [
>   {     "id": 159,
>           "hall_name": "asdad",
>           "image_path": "[\"1579635948.jpg\",\"1579635948.jpg\",\"1579635948.png\",\"1579635948.png\"]"
>       },
>       {
>           "id": 160,
>           "hall_name": "dsfdsf",
>           "image_path": "[\"1579636069.jpg\",\"1579636069.png\",\"1579636069.png\",\"1579636069.png\"]"
>       },
>       ]

**I want to display the first value from all `image_path`like this**

> [ {
>
> > ```
> >     "id": 160,
> >     "hall_name": "dsfdsf",
> >     "image_path": "["1579636069.jpg"]"
> > },
> > ]
> > ```

Comment: Could you plz add an example of desired output result ?

Comment: example  output i need to display the first value from array (image_path).. output i need like this (1579635948.jpg). just the first value not all .

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: please to help me but when write your code in my project i have this error......( ErrorException: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in file C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\project web\laravel_pro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 291 –

Comment: Did you write this line  $array = json_decode($hall->image_path, true); before $hall->image_path = reset($array) ?? NULL;

Comment: yes i was written it the error display ErrorException: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in file C:

Comment: Could you plz dump(json_decode($hall->image_path, true)); and paste it here ?

Comment: thank you ..bro ،،The problem has been resolved

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

You may use `decode` your `$hall->image_path` string before loop through it

```
public function index() {
    $halls = DB::table('halls')
        ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
        ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')
        ->get();

    $results =[];

    foreach ($halls as $hall) {

        $array = json_decode($hall->image_path, true);

        if (is_array($array)) {

           $hall->image_path = reset($array) ?? NULL;

           array_push($results, $hall);
        }
    }

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the whole collection data but with modified **image_path** column, so it contains only the first path, right?

Here is the code using **[map helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map)** to output the collection as you desire:

```
public function index() {
    $hall=DB::table('halls')
        ->join('imagas','halls.id','=','imagas.id_Halls')
        ->select('halls.id','halls.hall_name','imagas.image_path')
        ->get();

    $results = $hall->map(function ($item, $key) {
        is_array($item->image_path) ? [head($item->image_path)] : [$item->image_path];
        return $item;
    });

    return response()->json($results);

// [ { "id": 159, "hall_name": "asdad", "image_path": "["1579635948.jpg"]" }, 
//   { "id": 160, "hall_name": "dsfdsf", "image_path": "["1579636069.png"]" }]
}
```

Comment: please to help me but when write your code in my project  i have this error......( ErrorException: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in file C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\project web\laravel_pro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 291